# Can anyone help me figure out what syntax crime I'm committing here?

Tags: mysql

I'm on the verge of tearing my hair out. I"m an absolute neophyt to mysql, and i've created a table, and i'm simply trying to add an auto_increment to the table.   This is the mysql code i've added to alter the table.

```
ALTER TABLE
    'student_information' MODIFY COLUMN 'Index_No' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

I continue to get this error

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''student_information' MODIFY COLUMN `Index_No` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT' at line 2"

Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Quotes need to be backticks.

Comment: ...or simply omitted altogether

Comment: Maybe change the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow, have you tried the following one?

```
ALTER TABLE `student_information` MODIFY COLUMN `Index_No` INT auto_increment
```

**1)** It's better to remember that `NOT NULL` becomes useless when what the parameter affects is an `auto_increment` field.

**2)** Also, don't use `'parameter'` for parameters, because it will always throw an error in *MySql*. You can avoid to put them or you can just use, instead:

```
`parameter`
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!  I figured it was something very minor and completely syntax related that I was screwing up.  As it turns out, I was using the *single quotes* (' '), which phpmyadmin doesn't use for editing columns, but rather table elements.  So all I had to do was switch to the *back quotes* (``), before I could get the right result.

Comment: Always happy to help people, have a nice day :)